# My JSON reads is not compiling when there is an Option[Instant] property on my case class

Tags: scala, play-json

How do I write the json reads for a class that has an option Instant property?

```
case class User(id: Int, joined: Option[Instant])
```

My IDE is showing the error:

> No implicit found for parameter: Reads[Option[Instant]]

```
implicit val userReads: Reads[User] = (
  (__\ "id").read[Int] and 
  (__ \ "joined").read[Option[Instant]]
 )(User.apply _ )
```

If I remove the Option than the Instant works fine.

Why doesn't it allow the options for an Instant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try to resolve `Option[T]` in such case, but use `readNullable`.

```
import java.time.Instant

case class User(id: Int, joined: Option[Instant])

import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

implicit val userReads: Reads[User] = (
  (__ \ "id").read[Int] and 
  (__ \ "joined").readNullable[Instant]
 )(User.apply _)
```

Also, it easier in such case to use the provided macro:

```
import java.time.Instant

case class User(id: Int, joined: Option[Instant])

import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val userReads: Reads[User] = Json.reads[User]
```

Comment: If you have time, can you explain why Option[T] won't work?

Comment: Generally Option is a special case, as it can be encoded in different way according the context (null, omitted, ...), and it's derived for any `T: Reads`.

Comment: So in the JSON, to make the Instant value None what would the JSON have to include?

Comment: Null or omit, just try